# TouchableOpacity not working on expo for react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Am working on this login page where I had to use TouchableOpacity on a this text "Already have an account? Sign in instead!" to send me to the singin screen and for some reason it didn't work so naturally I thought I had an error in my code and after hours of debugging I had the idea to make a simple button with the same functionality and it works for am wondering is there something wrong with TouchableOpacity on expo or there is somekind of logic error i missed.

here is the code i used :

From my signup screen :

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationEvents onWillBlur={clearErrorMessage} />
      <AuthForm
        headerText="Sign Up for Tracker"
        errorMessage={state.errorMessage}
        submitButtonText="Sign Up"
        onSubmit={signup}
      />
      <NavLink
        routeName="Signin"
        text="Already have an account? Sign in instead!"
      />
    </View>
  );
```

from the Navlink component :

```
return (
    <>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routeName)}>
        <Spacer>
          <Text style={styles.link}>{text}</Text>
        </Spacer>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Button
        title="go to sing in"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("Singin");
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
```

Comment: braces are differents. On your touchableOpacity try wrapping your `navigation.navigate(routeName)` like you did with the button. I don't know if it will works but I don't see anything wrong here, unless your `routeName` variable is undefined or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `routeName` is not a name. You said that you had the idea to make a simple button with the same functionality and it works.
It works is because you give the right `routename` as "Singin"

So you just replace

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routeName)}>
```

with

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Singin")}>
```

should be work.